# sorting in alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to sort the list in alphabetical order by clicking on the title. when you click again in the opposite alphabetical order. I do not know how to implement this. Maybe I do not understand how the sort method works, but I've tried different options and nothing works. It does not turn out to do sorting by repeated clicking on the header

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Таблица</title>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
    <div class="table-title">
        <h3>Участники:</h3>
    </div>
    <table id="myTable" class="table-fill">
      <tr>
        <th class="list_link number">Номер</th>
        <th class="list_link lastname">Имя</th>
        <th class="list_link name">Фамилия</th>
        <th class="list_link age">Возраст</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Яванов</td>
        <td>Петр</td>
        <td>19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Аетров</td>
        <td>Яков</td>
        <td>18</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Сидоров</td>
        <td>Евгений</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Ушаков</td>
        <td>Кирилл</td>
        <td>17</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var trArr = $('tr').not('tr:first-child')
    var tdArrNumbers = trArr.find('td:first-child')
    var tdArrLastname = trArr.find('td:nth-child(2)')  
    $('.lastname').click(function(){
        var tdArrLastnameText = []
        for (var i = 0; i < tdArrLastname.length; i++) {
            tdArrLastnameText.push(tdArrLastname[i].innerText)
        }
        var lOne = tdArrLastnameText[0].charAt(0);
        var lTwo = tdArrLastnameText[1].charAt(0);
        if (lOne > lTwo == true) {
            tdArrLastnameText.sort()
        }
        if (lOne < lTwo == true) {
            console.log('ff')
        }
    })
})
function seeResult (seeArr){
    var newTrArr = []
    for (var i = 0; i < seeArr.length; i++) {
        newTrArr.push(seeArr[i].closest('tr'))
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < newTrArr.length; i++) {
        $(myTable).append(newTrArr[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to sort your array, or your table?

Comment: I will suggest to get elements in an array and use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example.
As Dhaker said in his comment, I inserted some entries into a multidimensional array, then I used the sorting method.

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title> Type </title>  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table id="myTable">
          <th class="list_link lastname"> LastName </th>
          <th class="list_link name"> Name </th>
      </table>


      <script>

        var tLastName = [];
        var tName = [];
        var s_ind = 0;

        tArray = [["Aaa", "A000"],
              ["Ccc", "C111"],
              ["Bbb", "B222"]]



        function print_table(){
          for(var i=0; i<tArray.length; i++){

            newTr = "<tr id='tr"+i+"'> <td> "
              + tArray[i][0]
              + "</td> <td>"
              + tArray[i][1]
              + "</td> </tr>";
            $('#myTable').append(newTr);
          }
        }

        function sort_lastname(a, b){
          if (a[0] === b[0]) {
            return 0;
          }
          else {
            return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
          }

        }

        function update_table(){
          for(var i=0; i<tArray.length; i++){
            $("#tr"+i).remove();
          }
          if(s_ind == 0){
            tArray.sort(sort_lastname);
          }
          else{
            tArray.reverse();
          }
          print_table();
          s_ind = (s_ind+1)%2;
        }

        $('.lastname').attr("onclick","update_table()");
        print_table();

      </script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw you are already using jQuery. So, I assume you don't have problem with dependencies.

You should take a look at robust [datatables.js](https://datatables.net/) and do not reinvent the wheel. Its under 100kb file to work with. I hardly think it will effect the performance of your website. You can find more minimal solution later on.